# Weak Law of Large Numbers - Why Use $Pr()$ Statement With Limits?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

In the literature describing Law of Large Numbers, the law is described in terms of $X_1,..,X_n$ random variables which are i.i.d. with each $X_k$ having mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. My question is, without getting into limits, we already see,

$$ \bar{X}_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i  $$

$$ E(\bar{X}_n) = E(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i)  $$

$$ = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i) = \frac{1}{n}n\mu $$

$$ = \mu $$

which proves the average of iid random vars approaches their individual expectation. This is an important result, and it would seem we are done. Then why is the other statement necesary, that says, for any $\epsilon > 0$

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} P(|\bar{X} - \mu| \le \epsilon) = 1$$

I do understand what this statement says, I am just not sure why it is required.

Comment: Your calculation does not show that the average approaches (in whatever sense) the individual expectation. It shows that the expectation of the average is the individual expectation. It could still have a huge variance. It is also not particularly important as it only shows that the expectation of the average is the average of the expectations, which is just linearity of the integral. The weak law formulation implicitely states that in the limit, the variance is comparatively small (the difference does not have fat tails).

Comment: Ah I see my mistake now, the expectation of the average is different than, the average (as arandom variable), _itself_ approaching $\mu$. The latter is much more important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You proved that $\overline X$ is an unbiased estimator of the mean $\mu$ - its expectation value is equal to $\mu$. This statement however doesn't tell you anything about the quality of estimation.

There are several other random variables which also have an expectation value of $\mu$. For instance, consider a family $Y_n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ of random variables which have a uniform distribution on $(\mu - n,\mu + n)$: We have $E(Y_n)=\mu$, but an increasing $n$ doesn't make the estimation better - the variance is proportional to $n^2$.

The weak law of large numbers tells a story about the actual value of the sample mean, and not only about the expectation of it:

For every given error bound $\varepsilon$, and each confidence level $1-\alpha \in (0,1)$, there is a number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, the probability that a measurement of $\overline X_n$ will be in the interval $(\mu -\varepsilon, \mu +\varepsilon)$ is at least $1-\alpha$.